# MySQL : Import Number Enclosed by Bracket from CSV

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv, database-design

I am trying to import reports in csv format to MySQL for further analysis process. But, I have find several negative numbers enclosed by bracket e.g ($184,919.02),
($182,246.50). If I use double format, it will become 0, but using varchar or text it appears.

I need it to be recorded in double format to automate some calculations in further analysis process. Is there any way to solve this problem? And also how to remove the $ (dollar) sign as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show, how do you import the csv into mysql? Maybe you have to define a function as described in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function.html) and do the conversion character by character ignoring ($).

Answer (score 1):

Load into a `VARCHAR` column.  Then update the column with `REPLACE(col, '$', '')` to get rid of the `$`.

Repeat to get rid of `,`, `-`, `(`, ')` and any other garbage that is in the way.

Better yet, us a real programming language (not SQL) to cleanse the data.  Many languages let you remove `-$,()` in a single pass.